# How to stop page from auto refreshing with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

I am quite new to web dev and currently, I work on a JS course. I have a problem with the automatic page refreshing that happens in Chrome and Safari also.

I have read that this refreshing can be caused by input submission in HTML but this problem occurs even when I do not use any type of button. In the code below, I tried to make a counter of the best score of all games when I guess the numbers, but I cannot record this score because my browser randomly refreshes my localhost and therefore all data is lost. As I said this problem occurs even when I do not use any type of submitting in my code (page randomly refreshes itself).

I have tried to disable adblocker in my browsers, but this did not help. Also, I tried to use `window.stop()` at the start and end of the code, but this did not seem desirable because safari always showed that it is still loading the page. Also, I have read that this can be caused by some sort of RAM optimization in the browser and therefore I tried to execute the code with only one tab open but this did not help either. I use Live Server extension with VS Code and therefore I do not run live server with node.js through terminal.

Because this problem occurs in multiple browsers I figured that it can be solved by some additional code in JS for example. Do you have any idea how could I solve this problem? I have run out of ideas at this point.

My Code:

```js
"use strict";

let secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
let score = 20;
let highScore = 0;

document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const guess = Number(document.querySelector(".guess").value);

  if (!guess) {
    // When there is no input
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "No Number";
  } else if (secretNumber === guess) {
    // When correct guess
    document.querySelector(".number").textContent = secretNumber;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Correct guess! ";
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "#228B22";

    if (score > highScore) {
      highScore = score;
      document.querySelector(".highscore").textContent = highScore;
    }
  } else if (secretNumber < guess) {
    // When guess is too high
    if (score > 1) {
      score--;
      document.querySelector(".score").textContent = score;
      document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Too High";
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".score").textContent = 0;
      document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "You lost the game.";
    }
  } else {
    // When guess is too low
    if (score > 1) {
      score--;
      document.querySelector(".score").textContent = score;
      document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Too Low";
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".score").textContent = 0;
      document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "You lost the game.";
    }
  }

  // Reseting Game With Button
  document.querySelector(".again").addEventListener("click", function() {
    score = 20;
    document.querySelector(".score").textContent = score;
    secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    document.querySelector(".message").textContent = "Start Guessing";
    document.querySelector(".number").textContent = "?";
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "#222222";
    document.querySelector(".guess").value = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Guess My Number!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
    <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
    <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
    <div class="number">?</div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="left">
      <input type="number" class="guess" />
      <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
    </section>
    <section class="right">
      <p class="message">Start guessing...</p>
      <p class="label-score"> Score: <span class="score">20</span></p>
      <p class="label-highscore">
         Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently, I use this Chrome version "Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (arm64)" and this Safari version "Version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.3)" with MacBook Air(2020) with M1 chip and 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: `<button type="button">`

Comment: @epascarello That shouldn't matter if there's no `<form>`

Comment: Your code also binds a click event inside of a click event so you will get multiple click events attached to `.again"`

Comment: When does the reload happen? Check you click something? When you change something? When you dance around to the music in the background? When you eat popcorn?

Comment: @Barmar We been around long enough that I never trust the code posted in the question. lol

Comment: @epascarello The reload happens randomly. When I type in console.log("Test") in JS and just watch the console in Chrome or Sarafi it just reloads the page randomly.

Comment: Well by default a browser is not going to randomly reloAd a page without being told to do so. So you need to start to disable extensions and figure out if your development server has some live reloading going on.

Comment: This works through the "run code snippet" I would like to think this is something with your development setup. You could try to set up a debugger in your IDE and set a lot for breakpoints and wait until a reload happens. 
Here is a link for VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a problem with refreshing browser windows with localhost when loading code from external SSD. I disabled the Live Server extension in VS Code and installed node.js and run the live server from there but this did not help either. **When I moved my files from the external SSD into the machine everything worked correctly.**

Comment: Sounds like the filesystem you're using on the SSD is incompatible with the file watcher used by Live Server.

Answer (score 3):

> I use Live Server extension with VS Code…

This extension is designed to refresh your browser every time your file is changed (in some cases using the file buffer in VSCode). Disable the extension if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: Like I said this happens even when I do not have any type of input with submitting button. I can just log something in console (like "test") and when I watch the console in the browser it will reload the page in random intervals.

Comment: @GregorG. I suggest you try disabling the extension. Browsers do not simply refresh pages constantly.